# Error Missing or insufficient permissions in React app

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

- I'm having a problem trying to access the firestore in my React App project
- Specifically, I have a code to register a user with firebase authentication and after success will setDoc the user to firestore.
- Successfully authenticated user registration but cannot setDoc to firestore, specific error "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions."
  Please help me to solve that problem.

This my signup with Firebase authentication

```
function signUp(email,password){
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
            setDoc(doc(db,'users', email),{ 
                 savedShows:    []
             }) 
        }
```

and this's my cloud Firestore rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{email} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == email;
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == email;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aside from Frank's answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is an asynchronous call, so the call won't be done immediately.

You need to either `await` for it to be done, or use `then` to only add to the database once it's done.

So:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password).then((cred) => {
  setDoc(doc(db,'users', email), { 
    savedShows: []
  }) ;
});
```

Or (if you're in an async context):

```
const cred = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
await setDoc(doc(db,'users', email), { 
  savedShows: []
})
```